# Laravel Breeze Multi Auth Two register forms with different routes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-authentication

I'm using laravel breeze as auth scaffolding package I want to create this stuff :

**The auth countrollers :**

**app\Http\Controllers\Auth\Buyer**

> If the Visitor choose to Create an account "Sign Up" as "Buyer" it
> will redirect him/her to specified "register" page made only for
> "Buyers accounts".

**app\Http\Controllers\Auth\Seller**

> If the Visitor choose to Create an account "Sign Up" as "Seller" it
> will redirect him/her to specified "register" page made only for
> "Sellers accounts".

**The auth views :**

**resources\views\auth\buyer**

```
register.blade.php
```

**resources\views\auth\seller**

```
register.blade.php
```

**resources\views\auth**

```
login.blade.php
confirm-password.blade.php
forgot-password.blade.php
reset-password.blade.php
verify-email.blade.php
```

Comment: [Abbas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4587048) wrote an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66073628) saying "read this link in laracast ... https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-8-multi-auth-with-two-diffirent-registration-form"